# How to execute a shell script inside a unix server using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: linux, azure, shell, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to run a shell script inside a Unix server using Azure Logic Apps.

I tried several approaches to execute the shell script 1.(in the diagram). Can anyone suggest me a new approach or any idea to execute the shell2 from shell 1.

```
#!/bin/sh
touch testing.txt

HOST = '10.2.166.122'
USER = 'johndoe'
PASSWD = 'abc@123'
FILE = 'shell2.sh'
PATH = '/appdata/files/samplefile/bin'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd $PATH
execute $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Basically i need to pass the server credentials as well as server shell script location path as parameters.

[image: Design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run your shell scripts with Run Command remotely using the VM agent. Run Command can be used through the Azure portal, REST API, or Azure CLI for Linux VMs.

For more details you could refer to this doc: [Run shell scripts in your Linux VM with Run Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command).

And in your situation, I think what you want is the REST API, so you could post the request, and in the logic app you could also use the REST API to send the request.

And this is the REST API: [Virtual Machines Run Commands - Run Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual%20machines%20run%20commands/runcommand).